# How to make an object network serialize to a file, not a SharedObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Currently, I do serialize my model object to the **SharedObject instance**:

```
 try {

     var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("sig");

     mySo.clear();
     mySo.data.model = _model;
     mySo.flush();

  } catch ( e:Error ) {

    Alert.show( 'Leider konnte kein Modell geladen werden.' );

  }
```

Likewise, I load the saved model using the SharedObject instance. Works great.

Ultimately, I'd like to **serialize it to a file** - which fails. Here is how:

```
 var fp: File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;

 fp = fp.resolvePath( PREFS_FILENAME );

 var    _prefsStream:FileStream;
 _prefsStream = new FileStream();
 _prefsStream.open( fp, FileMode.WRITE );
 _prefsStream.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;

_model.writeExternal( _prefsStream );
_prefsStream.close();
```

The complementing read operation suddenly breaks and reports missing bytes.

**In fact, I can't image how FileStream / _model.writeExternal() is able to serialize**, since it needs to somehow know, that a new serialization operation is about to start. If it doesn't know, it won't be able to determine, which object instances are **left to serialize**.

Thus, I image that my concept is completely wrong or I missed how to initialize the serialization operation.

**Please explains, what I'm missing.**

I'd be happy to read the raw ByteArray from the shared object and write it to a file. Unfortunately, I didn't find a method to retrieve from a SharedObject a ByteArray of a certain property, in my case `mySo.data.model`.
My question is loosely related to this one: [Why does delete( DictionaryInstance[ key ] ); fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694075/why-does-delete-dictionaryinstance-key-fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had to perform unit tests on an externalization framework I built and this is how I did it:

```
byteArray.writeObject(myObject);
byteArray.position = 0;
readValue = byteArray.readObject();
```

Also, I don't think you should have to worry about byte order, I think the default is big endian anyways.

So, for your case, I think you need something like:

```
fileStream.writeObject(myObject)
```

as opposed to:

```
myObject.writeExternal(_prefsStream);
```

The runtime should call `writeExternal` on your model automagically.

Comment: Regarding the byte order: Wanted to make sure that the code is cross-platform. Just to make sure ;-) Ah, writeObject() might be the essential point! Let's see. Will come back...

Comment: Thank you very much! Great hint! OK, writeObject() seems to prepare/maintain the list of already serialized object instances and all the magical rest. Still: How does writeObject() know, that a fresh serialization operation just started? I mean, how does it know, that it needs to save all reachable object instances?

Comment: It crawls the object tree. For example, every call to `writeObject` does a test to see if the object implements `IDataOutput` or `IExternalizable`. If so, it calls `writeExternal` on the object to give it a chance to serialize itself. If not, it tries to serialize it  as best as it can (using public properties etc.) or if it's a simple object (ie String, Number, Object, Array, etc) it simply calls into those methods to serialize it. I've served my time fighting with `IExternalizable`, but once you get the hang of it, you can do pretty cool stuff.

Comment: Also, so if a custom class serializes another custom class, it just repeats and keeps crawling the tree until the entire tree is serialized.

Comment: But suppose I call writeExternal later on again. The runtime somehow needs to know, that a fresh serialization operation is about to start. Doesn't it?

Comment: Why would you manually call `writeExternal`? The runtime calls that for you when you call `writeObject`.

Comment: Type. Rule of thumb: To serialize, implement the methods writeExternal() and readExternal(): Inside these routines and which writing to or reading from a serialization destination/source, always use writeObject() and readObject().